# How to generate nested for loops on the fly in python

Tags: python, for-loop, nested, on-the-fly

Imagine having a list (d) that is made of other lists with different lengths. We want to create a new list that looks like the result bellow. But obviously in this case everything is clear, we have a, b and c so we can create nested loops.

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [10, 20]
c = [100, 200, 300]

d = [a, b, c]

ret = []
for a1 in a:
    for b1 in b:
        for c1 in c:
            ret.append([a1, b1, c1])

print ret
```

Which results in this:

```
[[1, 10, 100], [1, 10, 200], [1, 10, 300], [1, 20, 100], [1, 20, 200], [1, 20, 300], [2, 10, 100], [2, 10, 200], [2, 10, 300], [2, 20, 100], [2, 20, 200], [2, 20, 300]]
```

What if we only have d with unknown number of lists in which there are unknown number of elements like bellow?

```
d = [[1, 2, 3], [10], [100, 200, 300, 400]]
```

Comment: Have you checked out `itertools`?

Comment: itertools is the way to go

Comment: Yes, `itertools.product`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is `itertools.product`:

```
import itertools
a = [1, 2]
b = [10, 20]
c = [100, 200, 300]
d = [a, b, c]
ret = list(itertools.product(a, b, c))  # Or list(itertools.product(*d))
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot Hai Vu